# Regex decimal greater than 0 less than 1 with at most 3 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a decimal number that is greater than 0 and less than 1, with at most 3 decimal places. So 0, 0.0004, 0.00, 00.004, are NOT valid. But 0.004 is valid.

I thought this shall be simple but couldn't get it working.
This is what I came up with: `/^0(?:\.)([1-9]{1,3}?$)/g` which makes `0.004` invalid but `0.004` is valid.

Comment: 0 and 1 should be excluded?

Comment: `[1-9]` excludes 0 from your decimal part... You'll have to to replace it with `[0-9]` and maybe check that the last digit is not 0

Comment: try this [`\b0\.(?!0+\b)\d{1,3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/WdqxrS/2)

Comment: I assume want to know if the string representation of a decimal number satisfies certain requirements. If so, you need to edit to clarify that you are dealing with strings, and show example strings with quotes. Could you not check that by converting the string to a float and then back to a string and then check if the result equals the original string? Also, is `'0.040'` valid?

Comment: Yes `0.040` is valid.

Comment: It seems strange that `'0.040'` is valid but `'0.00'` is not.

Comment: 0.00 is NOT greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead assertion to disallow all zeroes after dot:

```sh
^0\.(?!0+$)\d{1,3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pnmoyf/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `0\.`: Match `0.`
- `(?!0+$)`: Make sure we don't have all zeroes ahead
- `\d{1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 digits
- `$`: End

Above regex uses anchors assuming only one such number per line. If there are multiple decimal numbers per line then use word boundary instead of anchors:

```
\b0\.(?!0+$)\d{1,3}\b
```

---

If trailing `0` is not be allowed after dot then use:

```
^0\.\d{0,2}[1-9]$
\b0\.\d{0,2}[1-9]\b
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pnmoyf/3)

Comment: If trailing `0` is not be allowed after dot then use: `^0\.\d{0,2}[1-9]$`

Answer (score 3):

While regex tend to be short, they're also cryptic. If you're open to alternatives:

```js
const validate = n => {
  n = Number.parseFloat(n) * 1000;
  return Number.isInteger(n) && n > 0 && n < 1000;
};
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of doing validation like this. The format in question is just part of the validation requirement; the part of regex already works.

Comment: That you're asking the question at all may demonstrate that a regex solution may also be a maintenance problem. I believe that part of writing good code is writing maintainable code.

Comment: I agree actually. Not a big fan of regex myself; in fact before this I never really wrote any complex regex:)

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression should do the trick

```regex
^0\.\d{1,3}$
```

You can test it here

https://regex101.com/r/IwQsaD/1

Comment: This seems to have done it. Knew it would be simple! Thanks.

Comment: This one doesn't meet your requirement to reject `0.00`. anubhava's does.

Comment: @aamarks ah yes, thanks for pointing that out.